# Continuous uploading of images to twitpic fails

Tags: iphone, image, twitpic

I am doing an application in which I am uploading the images to twitpic. It works fine the first time. But if I try to upload the next image within that minute itself, it shows a 401 error. If I try again after waiting for a minute, it gives a 200 response and works fine. Why is this happening? Can I send images continuously to twit pic without any interruption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the documentation of TwitPic states that there is 500 call limit on the API.
And the 401 will happen only if you do supply the correct Auth header.

My guess is that there is something wrong with the auth header, it might be due to caching.
If you use NSURLConnection nochache paramter:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
```

Comment: rckoenes i am using this : ASIFormDataRequest *req = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitpic.com/2/upload.json"]];
    [req addRequestHeader:@"X-Auth-Service-Provider" value:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json"];
    [req addRequestHeader:@"X-Verify-Credentials-Authorization"
                    value:[oAuth oAuthHeaderForMethod:@"GET"                                   andUrl:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json"
                                            andParams:nil]];

Comment: `ASIHTTPRequest` does not use cache bij default, so you should be good. The documentation states that the 401 error means that you are missing the auth headers.

Comment: I think that there will be some call limit on the twitpic API

Comment: The [`twitpic` doucmentation](http://dev.twitpic.com/docs/) specifies a call lint as `500 calls a day per ip` except for `Create or upload API calls` and `Retrieving image thumbnails`. Show you should be able to upload even if the rate limit is past. have a look at the `X-RateLimit-Limit` in e response.

Comment: It takes accurate 50 seconds for a 200 response.if the uploading interval is more than 50 seconds,it works fine.Do u have any other suggestions?